# Why unwanted data is pushed in my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, jquery-plugins

I want to create a form field where **multiple data** can be inserted using "add" button and after pressing "ok or submit" all the data from the form is posted.

After pressing "add" the data is pushed into an array callded formData.values . However, when I press the "add" button, the behavior is erratic.

```
Its output on console is like:
1st trial -- typing "a" and pressing add button... formData.values = [a]
2nd trial -- typing "b" and pressing add button... formData.values = [a, a, b]
3rd trial -- typing "c" and pressing add button... formData.values = [a, a, b, a, b, c]
```

I want the values pushed like:

```
1st trial --- form.data.values should be [a]
2nd ---                        should be [a,b]
3rd ---                        should be [a,b,c]
```

This is my jQuery code: You can also see it in [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DrGeneral/6R6Pq/)

```
(function($){
$.fn.multiData = function( options ){
    var $this = this; 
    var id; // id of add button
    var defaults = { 
                    addMoreButton : true,
                    addCancelButton : true                        
        };
    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
    var formData;
    var addButton;

    this.on('focusin', ':input', function(){
        var $inputName = $(this);
        id = $inputName.data( 'more' );
        addButton = $(id);
        addButton.show();

        // getting value from <input name="value">
        formData.name = $inputName.attr('name');
        console.log(formData.name + ' formData.name' );
    });

    this.on('focusout', ':input', function(){
        //id = $(this).data( 'more' );
        //id = '#' + id;
        var focussedBox = $(this);
        var textBoxData = $.trim( $(this).val() );
        if( textBoxData === '' ){
            addButton.hide();//$(id).hide();
        }
        else{
            addButton.on( 'click', function( event ){
                event.preventDefault();

               // **THESE 3 LINES** IS WHERE I WANT HELP
                console.log( 'initial ' + textBoxData );
                formData.values.push( textBoxData );
                console.log( 'ln 37 testBoxData=' + textBoxData + ' formData.values=' + formData.values + ' ' + formData.values.length);

                $(this).hide();//$(id).hide(); or addButton.hide() but later wont work dont know why.
                focussedBox.val(''); // clearing the field after adding data.

                formData.show();
                });
            }
        });


        formData = {
            name: null,
            values: [],
            show: function(){
                $('#result').html( this.values );
            }
        };

        console.log( settings );
        return this; // to enable chaining
    };

    // form-div is used multiple times so storing it for quick response
    var formDiv = $('#form-div');
    formDiv.removeClass('no-js');

    // checking if javascript is on or not. If off disabled = true
    var disabled = formDiv.hasClass('no-js');
    if( !disabled ){
        formDiv.multiData();
    }
    else {
        alert( 'javascript is disabled' );
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
formData.show();
$( this).unbind( "click" );//just add this line
```

Reason : Because you are binding click everytime you are hovering. so once you click button that many click event are fired.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6R6Pq/21/)**

Comment: That did the trick but I didn't understand the reason though. Can you clarify it please.

Comment: simple on every focusout you are binding click event to button.n times you focusout n times you bind event. so when button clicked, n times click function is called.